# Non-polynomial splines, a non-linear problem

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, interpolation, splines

I'm looking for references on how to construct spline-like functions from a basis that does not include piecewise polynomials.

To be specific, given a class of functions such as "decaying exponentials" or "sines and cosines" (which are parameterized by a single parameter, *e.g.* the decay rate or the frequency), is there an efficient and numerically stable method to construct a function that is piecewise a linear combination of $N$ such functions (whose parameters are to be determined), interpolates given data $(x_k,f_k)$ [which are assumed to be such that they can be interpolated using the given function class, *i.e.* *e.g.* monotonically decreasing for decaying exponentials] and has continuous derivatives at $x_k$ up to order $2N-2$ (in order to fix $N$ linear coefficients and $N$ non-linear parameters)?

I can of course write down the explicit equations needed to satisfy these conditions, but directly solving those using a non-linear equation system solver does not look too promising as an approach.

What literature I could find so far on splines with non-polynomial components referred to spaces spanned by polynomials and some given non-polynomial. Here I'm looking for the case where there are no polynomials and the non-polynomial functions are parameterized by a parameter whose values are to be determined by the interpolation and smoothness conditions.

Comment: one strategy that comes to mind is to proceed analogous to the B-Spline technique, i.e. construct basis functions of minimal support with the smoothest possible transition to $f(x)\equiv 0$ and attempt to meet the goal of making the collection of basis functions a partition of unity. Then solvong the interpolation task amounts to evaluating the basis functions at the knots and solving a system of linear equations.

Comment: here is a download link describing exponential splines https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiD_JGNxNPnAhXmw8QBHW1hApAQFjABegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcore.ac.uk%2Fdownload%2Fpdf%2F82112125.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0nvVKzO_qYZXqCnrjlGOqE

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the link. I was aware of the McCartin paper, which to my understanding deals with spline interpolation in $\mathrm{span}\{1,x,e^{px},e^{-px}\}$, which is why I stated that existing work seems to deal with mixed polynomial-exponential bases. The problem I'm asking about is different in that the function space to which the splines piecewise belong doesn't contain polynomials of any degree (except possibly constants), and that the non-linear parameter(s) $p$ are to be determined by the interpolation and continuity conditions.

Comment: Could you provide an exemplary example of what kind of functions you have available and which parameters have to be determined as part of the interpolation task? My assumption was that the set of functions is fixed up to multiplication with a constant, but apparently you need something that goes beyond smoothly piecing  a linear combination of given functions.

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity. What I'm looking for is a way to both pick a finite-dimensional subspace of an infinite-dimensional space and the unique element of that subspace that satisfies the given conditions. E.g. from "decaying exponentials", i.e. $\{e^{-\alpha x}|\alpha>0\}$, four conditions pick an element $s(x)=Ae^{-\alpha x}+Be^{-\beta x}\in\mathrm{span}\{e^{-\alpha x},e^{-\beta x}\}$. The problem is precisely the non-linearity of the task.

Comment: Just a remark: if the $1$ and $x$ are in the span, then at least granting continuity of the resulting curve poses no problem; otherwise already that would pose severe difficulties for arbitrary non-polynomial function bases.

Comment: @ManfredWeis I agree that arbitrary non-polynomial bases will be a nightmare in general. I may have overgeneralized my actual problem ... for decaying exponentials or cosines, I see no problem with continuity.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer, but I guess it is more than a comment.

One way to reduce the task is to apply the spirit of VARPRO to separate the linear coefficients and the non-linear parameters, i.e. alternatingly solve $N$ of the conditions as a linear equation system for the coefficients of the solution in a given $N$-dimensional subspace, and solve the remaining $N$ conditions as a non-linear system for $N$ parameters giving a different subspace (in which the coefficients, being kept fixed, are those of the solution to those other $N$ conditions). This reduces the problem size by a factor of two.

Comment: For the case of $N=2$, there is a somewhat canonical-looking way to split the equations by solving the interpolation conditions as linear equations for the coefficients, and the smoothness conditions as non-linear equations for the parameters, but sadly this does not generalize to $N\ge 3$, where the split between the equations appears to be necessarily arbitrary.

Comment: regarding the functions $Ae^{ax}$ it should be noted that $A$ and $a$ do not imply two degrees of freedom because $A$ is a "shape-preserving" shift of $e^{ax}$ along the $x$-axis. For $C^1$ continous splining of that function class at least 3 functions $e^{a_ix}, e^{b_ix},e^{c_ix}$ are required on $[x_i,x_{i+1})$; the solution could be calculated symbolically and the $\lbrace a_i,b_i,c_i\rbrace$ chosen to optimize the solution w.r.t. further properties like curve length etc.

Answer (score 2):

The interpolant
$$A\left(e^{\frac{a}{A}(x-x_i)}-1\right)+B\cdot\left(\cosh\left(\frac{a}{A}(x-x_i\right)-1\right)+y_i\ =\  (A+B)\mathbf{e^{\frac{a}{A}(x-x_i)}}+B\cdot \mathbf{e^{-\frac{a}{A}(x-x_i)}}-(A+B)+y_i\\ 
a=\frac{d}{dx}S(x_i),\\ 
\Delta x_i=x_{i+1}-x_i,\\ 
\Delta y_i=y_{i+1}-y_i,\\ 
B=\frac{\Delta y_i-A\left(e^{\frac{a}{A}\Delta x_i}-1\right)}{\cosh\left(\frac{a}{A}\Delta x_i\right)-1}$$ solves the $C^1$ interpolation problem albeit not the periodic one.

The construction of the spline $S(x)$ happens from left to right and requires knowldege of the slope at $x_0$ to be able to calculate the Interpolant that connects $(x_0,y_0)$ with $(x_1,y_1)$; knowing the interpolant we can determine the slope at $x_1$ and we are in the same situation as before so that eventually $S(x)$ is determined.

The underlying ideas that led to identifying the interpolant for $C^1$ continuous interpolation can most likely be generalized to higher degrees of smoothness but I'm still on my way.

**Addendum:**
parameter $A$ provides limited control over the shape of the interpolant:

- if we want the "purest" expontial functions, the $A$ should be chosen to minimize $B$
- if we strive for preserving shape we can chose $A$ to control the abscissa of the (unique) local extremum in cases of $y_i\lt y_{i+1}\land y_{i+2}\lt y_{i+1}$

  - align it with the vertex of the parabola through $\left(\,(x_i,y_i),\,(x_{i+1},y_{i+1}),\,(x_{i+2},y_{i+2})\,\right)$
  - align it with the abscissa of the intersection of the line with slope $a$ that contains $(x_i,y_i)$ and the line through $(x_{i+1},y_{i+1})$ and $(x_{i+2},y_{i+2})$

Comment: Your interpolant does not appear to depend on $x$ at all. Is that right?

Comment: @gvmh you are right; the definition of $\ksi$ amd \eta$ were flawed; I corrected that; thanks for bringing it to my attention

Answer (score 0):

if the functions to be "splined" are invertible on the intervals $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ and, if $f_{i-1}(x)$ and $f_i(x)$ are two such functions that are invertible on $[x_{i-1},x_i]$, resp. on $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$, additionally $f_{i-1}^{-1}(x_i)=f_i^{-1}(x_i)$
then $$S(x)\ :=\ \mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big(\mathcal{S}\big(x_i,\mathcal{F}\left(y_i+\gamma(x_i)\,\right)\big)\Big)-\gamma(x) $$
yields an entire class of interpolating non-polynomial splines.  I used the "strange" notation in order to stress the analogy to signal processing: if the original interpolation task is non-polynomial in the "time"-domain then "transforming" the $y_i$ via the inverse functions makes the interpolation polynomial in the "frequency" domain; interpreting interpolation as filtering completes the analogy to signal processing.
The key concept is [Homomorphism](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Homomorphism.html) and was introduced to signal processing in [R.W. Schafer "Echo removal by discrete generalized linear filtering". Res. Lab. Electron. MIT, Tech. Rep. (1969)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiS55HCh8b5AhWugv0HHZCkBHgQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdspace.mit.edu%2Fbitstream%2Fhandle%2F1721.1%2F4277%2FRLE-TR-466-04517463.pdf%3Fseque..&usg=AOvVaw3WPFAAi9dlV8gOzTF1eeT1)

The $\gamma(x)$ is a way to allow for mixed interpolation, e.g. exponentials plus polynomials; the case $\gamma(x)\equiv \mathrm{const}$ seem interesting in its own right when investigating the spline's limit behavior for e.g. $\gamma(x)\equiv \mathrm{const}\,\to\,\infty$, especially in the case of exponential splines.

Maybe its worth mentioning albeit trivial that this "homomorphic" splining directly carries over higher dimensions or parametric interpolation and one isn't limited to polynomials in the "frequency" domain; rational interpolants would be the "next bigger thing" to use.

**Addendum:**
the notation I used is aimed at emphasizing the analogy to transformation from the time domain to the frequency domain e.g. via a Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$; the analogy to interpolating $(x_i,y_i)$ with exponential splines $S(x)\in C^{k-1}$ of the form $e^{\sum_{j=0}^k a_{ij}x^j}, S(x_i)=y_i$ is that the tranformation $\mathcal{F}$ corresponds to applying the analogy of the Fourier transformation $\mathcal{F}$, i.e. the inverse $\ln(\cdot)$ of $e^{(\cdot)}$, to the ordinates $y_i$ of the data to be interpolated and then calculate the interpolating polynomial spline with these transformed ordinates; that spline is denoted by $\mathcal{S}(x)$ because it is calculated in the analogy of the frequency domain.
the final step is to go back to the analogy of the time domain by applying the analogy $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$, i.e. $e^{(\cdot)}$ of the inverse Fourier transformation to $\mathcal{S}(x)$ to obtain the interpolating spline $S(x)$ in the analogy of the time domain.

The $\gamma(x)$ allow for modeling situations where the data is "almost" polynomial, i.e. if for some order $h$ the magnitudes of the divided differences of order $h$ become small, then it may, depending on the model of the origin of the data, improve the quality of the interpolating spline if the values of a "lower polynomial hull" at the abscissas $x_i$ are subtracted from the ordinates prior to the transition to the analogy of the frequency domain.
Another usecase for introducing $\gamma(x)$ is if one is only interested in the shape of the interpolating curve but the ordinates of the data are outside the value range of the interpolation curve, e.g. negative $y_i$ in the case of exponential splines; then adding $\gamma(x)$ can fix these issues.

An example may make things clearer:
assuming we have sampled an empirical distribution of which we assume that is the sum of Gaussian's that we would like to recover.
In that case an Ansatz could be to take the logarithm of the ordinates, calculate a quadratic spline and take the abscissas of apices of parabolas with negative leading coefficient as an initial guess for the central values of the Gaussians.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your notation here -- what precisely are $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ ? And how is $\gamma$ to be chosen?

Comment: @gmvh Thanks for coming back at me; I have added an explanation of the notation and also an example. I hope I managed to make things clearer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't quite get it: Taking the log and then splining gives a piecewise polynomial, whose exponential won't typically be a linear combination of piecewise exponentials. So while this is some kind of non-polynomial spline, I don't think it is the solution to to problem from the OP, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @gmvh agreed; the splines that are described do not depend on "horizontal-scaling" factors whose calculation is part of the interpolation task. For the case of exponentials that task seems to be explicitly solvable; I will eventually provide details.

Comment: For the exponential case with $N=2$, I've worked out a solution in terms of the Lambert $W$-function. If you can provide an explicit solution for the exponential case with $N>2$, that would be tremendous!