# Calculating non-polynomial spline functions

Tags: algorithms, interpolation, splines

> **Question:**
>
> what is known about the algorithmic construction of general interpolating spline functions with smoothness constraints at every knot?

So far I could only find descriptions for splining specific functions, like e.g. exponential splines or constructions of non-polynomial splines that are taylored for finding smooth solutions to certain boundary value problems.

In contrast to the similar question [Non-polynomial splines, a non-linear problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352683/non-polynomial-splines-a-non-linear-problem) I am *not* looking for splines of functions that depend non-linearly on parameters that have additionally to be determined in order to meet continuity or smoothness constraints.

Instead I have a (potentially different) set of $k$ arbitrary functions for every interval $\left[x_i,x_{i+1}\right]$ whose *linear* combinations have to be determined so that they constitute to an interpolating curve for the knots $\lbrace(x_i,y_i)\,|\,0\le i\le n,\,x_i\le x_{i+1}\rbrace$ that meets the continuity and smoothness constraints.